# What is probable origin of Basque word for city/town?

Tags: etymology, language-contact

The Basque word for 'town/city' is ***hiri***, with mute H. Could its origin be in Middle Eastern languages with its subsequent incorporation into Basque through the [Armenian Kingdom of Cilicia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Armenian_Kingdom_of_Cilicia)?

There is also a Hebrew cognate for the word, which is עיר.

Are there any reliable sources of etymology of this *Basque* word?

Comment: Have you got any evidence that _hiri_ and _עיר_ are cognates - or is this your personal observation?

Comment: What is the connection between Cilicia and the Basques?

Answer (score 3):

[This Basque etymological dictionary](https://www.sussex.ac.uk/webteam/gateway/file.php?name=lxwp23-08-edb.pdf&site=1) claims that the word is "of unknown origin", but that the variant forms *(h)uri* and *iri* have been recorded in toponymy of Rioja, Alava and Navarro (Basque-speaking regions) from the 11th Century onwards. This would suggest that they are of Basque origin (and would rule out your theory of incorporation through the Armenian Kingdom of Cilicia - as the forms were recorded in the region prior to the existence of the kingdom)

Answer (score 1):

From a draft of Lawrence Trask’s *Etymological Dictionary of Basque*, with abbreviations expanded by me:

> **hiri** (Labourdin, Bas-Navarre), **hí(r)i** (Souletin), **iri** (Alta Navarra, Salazar, Roncalese), **uri** (Vizcayan, Gipuzkoan) *noun* ‘town’. 1545 (but see below).
>
> From **ili*, of unknown origin, by rhotacism of /l/. Last form by Bizkaian /i/-backing. The Romans reported a town called *Iliberris* in south-central Spain, and this name looks remarkably like a Basque formation meaning ‘new town’ (*berri* ‘new’). But there is no other evidence for Basque speech so far south, and we must suppose either coincidence or an undocumented settlement in this area by Basque emigrants. A second *Iliberris* (modern *Elna*) is recorded in Rosselló (Pyrénées-Orientales) (Coromines 1995 s.v. Elna), [...] The form *(h)uri* is well recorded from the 11th century onward in the toponymy of Alava and the Rioja, while *iri* is equally well recorded from the 11th century in Navarra.

If you're willing to consider outright speculation, it's worth mentioning Sorin Paliga’s *Urbian* theory. According to this theory, there is a pre-Indo-European root **ol-* / **ul-* / **or-* / **ur-*, connected with the concept of a town, present in this Basque word, Latin *urbs*, the name of the Swiss city of Uri, the name of the Iraqi city of Erbil, Greek *labyrinthos* and several other words.